# How do I merge the audited fpr file with the newly scanned fpr file using the command line?

Tags: command, fortify

I want to merge an audited fortify .fpr file with the newly scanned .fpr file so that all audits and comments get reflected even in the new file. How do I merge the files using command line? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fprutility -merge -project <old.fpr> -source <new.fpr> -f <merged.fpr>`

Comment: This does not work.  It only retains the audits and comments from the old.fpr